# How to save an image to the disk after is done loading it into the view from an URL

Tags: java, android-glide

Im building an android app that needs to fetch an image from an url and, after is done displaying it into the image view, I want to store it in the hard drive of the phone so it can be use later without creating a new petition or depending on the cache.
Im using glide 4.9.0

Some of the solutions online include using some deprecated clases such as SimpleTarget and Target that wont be applicable in this project.

This is what I have so far.

```
    File file = new File(holder.context.getExternalFilesDir(null), fileName);
        if (file.exists()) {
            GlideApp.with(holder.context).load(file).into(holder.ivProductImage);
        } else {
            GlideApp.with(holder.context).load(urlImage).into(holder.ivProductImage);
            // save the image to the hard drive
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Step 1
Glide.with(mContext)
.load(images.get(position).getThumbnail())
.asBitmap()
.into(new Target<Bitmap>(100,100) {
    @Override
    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
        saveImage(resource,position);
    }
});

//Step 2
private String saveImage(Bitmap image, int position) {
    String savedImagePath = null;

    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + images.get(position).getName() + ".jpg";
    File storageDir = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    + "/Comicoid");
    boolean success = true;
    if (!storageDir.exists()) {
        success = storageDir.mkdirs();
    }
    if (success) {
        File imageFile = new File(storageDir, imageFileName);
        savedImagePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        try {
            OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
            fOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Add the image to the system gallery
        galleryAddPic(savedImagePath);
    }
    return savedImagePath;
}

//Step 3
private void galleryAddPic(String imagePath) {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(imagePath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    mContext.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

Comment: SimpleTarget is deprecated since version 4.8 and im currently using version 4.9

Comment: Use Target directly and make sure you implement onLoadCleared.

Comment: Target is also deprecated as i stated in the description of the question

Comment: Sorry didn't notice. Try changing Target to CustomViewTarget. Check out this link:  https://github.com/sjudd/glide/commit/b3b2d7aa84a5beb8eddea39f2ec0e8ba35ceaa20